# Grouping a RDD using an array

Tags: scala, rdd

I have a RDD with these elements:

```
("a", Array(1, 2)) | ("b", Array(3, 4)) | ("c", Array(1, 2))
```

I wish to group it using the array in order to have this:

```
(Array("a", "c"), Array(1, 2)) | (Array("b"), Array(3, 4))
```

How to do that (preferably in Scala)?

Comment: This should be straightforward, have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use arrays as keys using Spark's default partitioner, you'll have to group by the arrays converted to lists, then just map the results back to the structure you're after:

```
val input: RDD[(String, Array[Int])] = ???

val result: RDD[(Array[String], Array[Int])] = input
  .groupBy(_._2.toList) // group by array
  .values // keep values only, of type Iterable[(String, Array[Int])]
  .map(it => (it.map(_._1).toArray, it.head._2)) // map back to requested format
```

Comment: Your last `map` effectively destroys the partitioning of the data, since Spark will forget about this RDD's partitioner. May be ok depending on what the OP wants, but worth mentioning

Comment: I didn't know this limitation, as I can store the elements in a List I will improve the first RDD in order to simplify the grouping. Thank you for the explanation and the code.

Comment: @ArmandGrillet is the partitioning important to you ? You have to be aware that calling `map` on a paired RDD will result in Spark deleting the partitioning metadata of the RDD.

Comment: I think this is fine in my case. The first RDD will not be used anymore once I have the result and I only need the letters linked to specific arrays.